# As a dual EU citizen, which country should I vote in for european elections?

Tags: election, european-union, voter-registration

I am a dual EU citizen (which countries is irrelevant here, but both full EU members) and am wondering which of my two countries I should register to vote in for the next European Parliament Elections, in order to maximize the "value" of my vote.

Based on [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/16384) I can only vote in a single country, but [from this answer by the EU Commission](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getAllAnswers.do?reference=P-2013-010069&language=EN):

> the Commission considers that the possibility for EU voters with a dual nationality to choose where to vote should be encouraged.

My question comes from the observation that one person's vote doesn't exactly count as one in a variety of elections.

I assume variables to consider probably include ratio of elected parliament members to population (as the EU Parliament seats are [allocated according to degressive proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_European_Parliament_election#Apportionment_of_seats)), but there are probably other elements to take into account.

How should I approach this question, and what information should I take into account?

Comment: You may first want to double check that the other (or both) your nationalities allow non-resident voting. That isn't guaranteed across all the EU member states.

Comment: I think, that without knowing your views and both nationalities, this can not be answered. There's too many variables. However, with that data included, it might becomes too narrow a question for politics SE.

Answer (score 5):

You gain nothing if you vote where your vote counts most, and the candidate you vote for doesn't get elected. Probably.

- Is the predicted outcome in one of your countries particularly close? Your vote might help to make the difference.
- Are there "first past the fencepost" or "threshold" voting systems that would make your vote likely to be irrelevant?
- Do you feel a special affinity towards any one party or candidate, and do you want her or him to be elected?
- Do you dislike any one party or candidate, and would you use your vote 'tactically' to keep that candidate out?