# Have people been prosecuted or fined for multiple cross-countries voting in EU elections?

Tags: election, european-union, election-fraud

Per a [recent question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41632/can-a-british-citizen-living-in-france-vote-in-both-france-and-britain-in-the-eu) here, an EU citizen may only cast one vote in the EU elections, even if citizen of multiple EU countries.

I imagine however that unlike national elections, this kind of multiple-voting might not be so easy to check, since the EU itself doesn't organize the EU elections, but leaves them to member states.

So, have there been cases reported in the press where people have voted (or tried to vote) multiple times in EU elections, once per country? How were or how would such cases be detected?

N.B. I realize the EU elections don't garner that much interest from voters, so the incentive to do this kind of cheating might be pretty low to begin with.

Comment: But if less people vote an individual vote counts more so you can exercise a greater influence by voting twice than you could in a high-turnout election.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Giovanni di Lorenzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_di_Lorenzo), an Italian journalist living and working in Germany, did this in 2014 (he voted in an Italian consulate in Germany *and* again in a local German school) and mentioned this in a talk show. He claimed to be unaware that this was illegal. He was [indicted](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_di_Lorenzo#Verfahren_wegen_Doppel-Wahl) for this and later paid "a substantial sum" as a fine but was not convicted and the case was eventually dismissed.

Comment: What do you mean by "paid "a substantial sum" but was not convicted"? Does that mean he settled the charges without admitting guilt?

Comment: @divibisan "Das Ermittlungsverfahren wurde, nachdem di Lorenzo im November 2014 einen 'namhaften Betrag' als Strafe gezahlt hatte, eingestellt" - the case was dismissed after he paid a fine.